# Android Emulator (HAXM not compatible with windows)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I was about to create my first project in xamarin,
 and I want to use android emulator but unfortunately,
 I wasn't able to download HAXM which is required for the emulator.
 [image]

I tried to run my emulator but some error appeared regarding the HAXM installation, but I have HAXM installed once when I installed my Android Studio before.

Comment: What are your machine specs? You have an Intel chip right? Worst case, you can use the Visual Studio Android emulators which use Hyper-V instead of HAXM. Both are pretty equal performance wise.

Comment: Intel i5(skylake), 16GB ram.  
So I can't use emulator created on Android Studio?

Comment: Did you install Android Studio and Visual Studio + Xamarin on the same machine? If so, you likely have two instances of the Android SDK installed! If you've created emulators in Android Studio, they exist where Android Studio installed its instance of the SDK, but the Android SDK where VS installed it is not aware!

Comment: Also, what version of HAXM did you download and install?

Comment: On Android Studio, I downloaded the latest version. 
and in VS, It says that it's not compatible with windows.  
And yes, I installed them on the same machine..

Comment: Change the Android SDK location that Visual Studio is using, the the one Android Studio installed. Go to Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android Settings. Then chang ethe "Android SDK Location" to where your Android Studio installation location. Then you should start to see your emulators you made before.

Comment: In short I can use my Android Studio SDK for VS? 
How can I delete the VS Xamarin SDK for android studio because it takes my hdd space.

Comment: Yep! You should in fact only be using one SDK location. To remove the Android SDK that VS installed, set your location *back* to the location VS installed it, run the SDK manager, uninstall every package, then change the SDK location to the location Android Studio installed it, then delete the entire folder where VS installed it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139380/discussion-between-charles-galvez-and-suavepirate).

Comment: I was able to use Android Studio Emulator but, I needed to Open first my Android Studio then open my Emulator and run the Application from xamarin. But that works well, 
thank you.